# RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'UserMethods.is_user_authorized' was never awaited

Tags: python-3.x, telegram

Задача получить в ответ `True`, это будет значить, соединение с `telethon` успешно

```
from telethon import TelegramClient
import socks

client = TelegramClient('session_id',
    api_id=ID, api_hash=HASH,
    proxy=(socks.SOCKS5, 'proxy', socks5)
)

client.is_user_authorized()
```

Получаю ответ:

```
RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'UserMethods.is_user_authorized' was never awaited
  client.is_user_authorized()
```

p.s. прокси работает.
Насколько я понял, ошибка связана с вызовом асинхронной задачи. но я ничего такого не делал. 
Вот документация: https://telethon.readthedocs.io/en/stable/extra/basic/telegram-client.html

Answer (score 1):

я починил, надо было переустановить библиотеку:

Удалить telethon
и установить telethon-async